# Different order for cart product

Tags: commerce

I have using [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) and [Commerce Marketplace](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_marketplace). I have added 2 products into the cart (products from different stores).The problem is when I taken review order page it shows as different order, also different order created. What is wrong with me.I wish to add these two product as the same order.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have something misconfigured. With the Marketplace module, you'll actually have 3 orders created. One is a **Marketplace Order** and one is a **Store Order**. It appears that your **Store Orders** are being displayed instead of the **Marketplace Order**. Check your pane configuration and ensure that you've enabled the proper marketplace modules and that your Views are showing the **Marketplace Order**.